# Returning empty result from equalTo in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I need to handle the case when my database does not have any matching results for equalTo(). Currently the code below only returns if I have a matching item, in the case that there is no match it does not return at all. Please advise on how to handle this?

```
function getActivitySurvey(pin) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     var ref = admin.database().ref("activity-survey");
     ref.orderByChild("pin").equalTo(pin.toString()).once('child_added')
       .then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot) {
             resolve(snapshot);
          } else {
             reject(new Error('No ActivitySurvey'));
          }
      }).catch( () => {
        reject(new Error('No snapshot'));
      })
   })
}
```

Edit:
I've since modified the code to look like the below, in the event that a pin value that does not exist in the database is specified the only line that gets output to the console is 'getActivitySurvey', the function eventually times out but never returns:

```
function getActivitySurvey(pin) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('getActivitySurvey')
  var ref = admin.database().ref("activity-survey");
  ref.orderByChild("pin").equalTo(pin.toString()).once('child_added').then((snapshot) => {
      console.log('have snapshot')
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        resolve(snapshot);
      } else {
        console.log('Rejecting ActivitySurvey')
        reject('error');
      }
    }).catch( (err) => {
      console.log('Caught error')
      reject('err');
    })
})
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to query for records for which `pin`is null (or does not exist)?

Comment: Record does not exist -- so no match for a non-null pin in db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot detect whether a child exists with just a `child_added` listener. You'll need to use a `value` listener for that.

For example:

```
ref.orderByChild("pin").equalTo(pin.toString())
   .once('child_added')
   .then((snapshot) => {
      resolve(snapshot);
   });
ref.orderByChild("pin").equalTo(pin.toString()).limitToFirst(1)
   .once('value')
   .then((snapshot) => {
      if (!snapshot.exists()) {
         reject(new Error('No ActivitySurvey'));
      }
   });
```

Or with only one query:

```
ref.orderByChild("pin").equalTo(pin.toString()).limitToFirst(1)
   .once('value')
   .then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
         snapshot.forEach(function(child) { // will loop only once, since we use limitToFirst(1)
            resolve(child);
         });
      }
      else {
         reject(new Error('No ActivitySurvey'));
      }
   });
```

Comment: Well spotted, Frank, the fact that it works with `value` while it does not work with `child_added`!

Comment: Yes! Thanks very much.